# UIPickerView with image and text in swift?

Tags: json, swift, uipickerview

I need an example of UIPickerView with image and text in swift language using JSON loading concept

Comment: i tried it a lot but didn't got succedd

Answer (score 1):

Normally on Stack Overflow you want to be a little more clear with your questions and present a problem rather than a request. But no worries, I'll try to point you in the right direction.

Here is a tutorial I found on how to make a UIPickerView: http://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-in-swift/

Now to get JSON into there, I'd get a JSON array from my POST request using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

If you're also stuck at downloading the JSON, take a look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), which works really well with SwiftyJSON.